# Cannot create VM with uploaded image on Openstack (Devstack)

Tags: virtual-machines, openstack, disk-image

I am working on a very simple project with Openstack, using Devstack. Currently, I've been able to make networks, routers, Vm's without many issues. But here is where I am having trouble. I've created an Ubuntu cloud server image in my Openstack, but cannot seem to create an instance which uses this image. When I create the image, it begins loading the block storage and after a few seconds comes up with this error every time [this is a photo of the error received when trying to boot the instance on ubuntu added image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXmuW.png)

I've tried several things like changing the format of the image, even though I am certain it is QCOW2, and other image formats as well to resolve this, with no success. I am not skilled whatsoever with CLI and figure some changes may need to be made, to allow the use of the image for instances. Could anybody please help? I've watched videos online of people going through the steps in Horizon and it work perfectly, but when I perform the same steps, I receive the above error every time.

Answer (score 0):

It would help in debugging if you can browse the log files by using `grep` and passing the instance ID and the volume ID as search strings:

`$ sudo grep -ri <instanceID> /var/log/*`

`$ sudo grep -ri <volumeID> /var/log/*`

After you run the above, you can post the output of each of the above command's output in a separate paragraph. It can also help if you add `default = true` in the `DEFAULT` sections of the configuration files so that you can get verbose logging output. If you do this, ensure that you restart the services that correspond to the modified configuration files.

What's your `Instance Boot Source`? Is it "Boot from image (creates a new volume)"? If that's the case, what if you just do "Boot from image" without creating a new volume? That would present a simple check on whether you can create a basic instance without volume errors involved.

After you confirm that you can create an instance without a new volume involved, you can create another instance with a new volume and debug the volume issues.